# RxJava2: Multiple errors in zip'ed observables throw exception

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I execute multiple HTTP calls in parallel by zipping them up. Now 0..n of them can obviously fail. The thing is, when e.g. 2 calls fail at almost the exact time, error 1 is processed in `doOnError` and `onErrorReturnItem` but error 2 slips through and causes an exception. I think this happens if error 2 happens to come in while error 1 is still not processed entirely in those two onError operators.

It can be reproduced with the following simplified code:

```
buttonClick.flatMapSingle(action -> Single.zip(
                    Single.error(new Throwable("error 1")).delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                    Single.error(new Throwable("error 2")).delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                    (integer, integer2) -> true
            )
                    .doOnError(t -> Timber.d(t.getMessage()))
                    .onErrorReturnItem(true))
                    .subscribe();
```

So every once in a while this would throw:

```
D/Main: error 1
W/System.err: java.lang.Throwable: error 2
```

Shouldn't the `Single.zip` only be allowed to emit **one** error?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think it is because you have `onErrorReturnItem`, so it continues `zip` operator further

Comment: Issue posted: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4871

Comment: This question has been answered in the github issue. I believe it should be closed/answered with link to that issue.